# Javascript - change top style from "ul" as child from a div parent

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the top value from css using javascript but it doesn't work.

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="Down()">Move Down</button>
<div class="test">
    <ul>
        <li>Line one</li>
        <li>Line two</li>
        <li>Line three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    color:red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.test ul{
    position: relative;
    top:50px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function Down() {
    var class_obj = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    var ul_obj = class_obj.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    ul_obj.style.top = parseInt(ul_obj.style.top, 10) + 10 + "px"; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fUmJR/

What am I missing?

Comment: if u check the cosole log from the for that fiddle. After click it throws once exception Uncaught ReferenceError: Down is not defined

Comment: It's 2013. Don't use intrusive event handlers :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

Comment: Your problem is with the second call to `getElementsByClassName()`. That function is only supported on `document` > `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getElementsByClassName'`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to change the JS loading around a bit on jsFiddle.  Take a look at my image for some hints on how to proceed.  in debugging js, alert is your best friend!

[image: changes I made on jsfiddle to demonstrate how to get started fixing your code]

Comment: Not sure on `alert` being your best friend... The console might get jealous

Comment: -1. This doesn't solve the question. The reason the code doesn't work is because `getElementsByClassName()` is only supported on `document`. The second call fails (see console in the given example).

Comment: BenM, take a look at the console for this example in jsFiddle: "Down is not defined"  We differ a bit on approach, I guess.  This person is fairly new to js/fiddle (heck, I am new to fiddle). I see it as better to teach to fish rather than provide a fish.  your comment is helpful too, but there are many things to point out, such as "ul" is not a class name.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.Down = (function() {
    var ul_obj = document.querySelectorAll('.test ul');
    Array.prototype.slice.call(ul_obj).forEach(function(element){
        element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top||50) + 10 + 'px'; 
    })
});
```

function Down() in window.onload is a local variable with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` return lists not elements. And second, check that what parseInt returns is a number before applying the style.

All of this can be found by debugging the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code to do that in a way you imagined:

```
this.Down = function Down() {  
    var ul_obj = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    if(!ul_obj[0].style.top) ul_obj[0].style.top = '50px';
    ul_obj[0].style.top = parseInt(ul_obj[0].style.top, 10) + 10 + "px";  
}
```

and call the the function through

```
<button onclick="javascript:window.Down()">Move Down</button>
```

your code didn't work because your function was in the window.onload event so Down() wasn't even visible

Here is your solution: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUmJR/19/)

To make it more simple, if you want to avoid the if block (which is used because javascript can get style.top only from inline CSS formatting), you might consider using this code that includes offestTop:

```
this.Down = function Down() {  
    var ul_obj = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    ul_obj[0].style.top = parseInt(ul_obj[0].offsetTop, 10) + 10 + "px";  
}
```

but you need to set position:relative to your .test class!

Answer (score 0):

- JsFiddle was not working as you needed to change the option from "onload" to "No wrap - in "
- When you use methods such as "getElementsByClassName" or "getElementsByTagName" you get an array of items.  You therefore need to reference the first item of the array.

Notice below how I added a reference to the item.

```
function Down() {
    var oTest = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];  
    var oUl = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    oUl.style.top = parseInt(oUl.style.top, 10) + 10 + "px";  
}
```

- Additionally I noticed that you had the wrong method for the  element.  It should be "" and not "getElementsByClassName".